# Entity is empty using Core data in Today extension

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, widget, today-extension

I'd like to show photos in today extension using Core data. But, entity is empty. I don't any idea about that.

here is what I'm doing:

1. add app group in both of targets (app and extension)
2. check target membership in xcdatamodeld.
3. create CoreDataStack class for using Core data in today extension.

   ```
   class CoreDataStack {

   private init() {

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                          selector: #selector(mainContextChanged(notification:)),
                                          name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                          object: self.managedObjectContext)

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                          selector: #selector(bgContextChanged(notification:)),
                                          name: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave,
                                          object: self.backgroundManagedObjectContext)
   }
   static let sharedStack = CoreDataStack()
   var errorHandler: (Error) -> Void = {_ in }

   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
   lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

       let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "name")
       container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self](storeDescription, error) in
           if let error = error {
               NSLog("CoreData error \(error), \(error._userInfo)")
               self?.errorHandler(error)
           }
       })
       return container }()

   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
   lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
   return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
   }()

   @available(iOS 10.0, *)
   func performBackgroundTask(_ block: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext) -> Void) {
    self.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask(block)
   }


   deinit {
       NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
   }

   lazy var libraryDirectory: URL = {

   let urls = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group...")

   return urls!

   }()



   lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
       let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "name", withExtension: "momd")!
       return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
   }()

   lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
   let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel:
       self.managedObjectModel)
   let directory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.kr....")
   let urls = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.kr....")!.path
   let url = directory!.appendingPathComponent("name.sqlite")

   do {
       try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType:
           NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                          configurationName: nil,
                                          at: url,
                                          options: nil)
   } catch {
       // Report any error we got.
       NSLog("CoreData error \(error), \(error._userInfo)")
       self.errorHandler(error)
   }
   return coordinator  }()

   lazy var backgroundManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
   let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
   var privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
   privateManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
   return privateManagedObjectContext   }()

   @available(iOS 9.0, *)
   lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
   var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
   managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
   return managedObjectContext        }()


   @objc func mainContextChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
   backgroundManagedObjectContext.perform { [unowned self] in
       self.backgroundManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
       }
   } 
   @objc func bgContextChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
   managedObjectContext.perform{ [unowned self] in
       self.managedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave: notification as Notification)
           }
       }

   func saveContext () {
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
       if context.hasChanges {
           do {
               try context.save()
           } catch {
               // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
               // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
               let nserror = error as NSError
               fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
           }
       }
   } else {
       do {
           try managedObjectContext.save()
       } catch {
           // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
           // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
           let nserror = error as NSError
           NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
           abort()
               }

           }
        }

   }
   ```
4. add function in today extension view controller

   ```
   func fetchData() {

   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Quotes")

   if #available(iOS 10.0,*) {

       let context = CoreDataStack.sharedStack.viewContext

       do {
           let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

           self.quotes = results as? [Quotes]
           print("result = \(results)")


       } catch let error as NSError {

           print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")

           return
       }
   }else {
       //for ios 9.3~
       let context = CoreDataStack.sharedStack.managedObjectContext

       do {
           let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

           self.quotes = results as? [Quotes]
           print("result = \(results)")


       } catch let error as NSError {

           print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")

           return
       }
   }

   for i in self.quotes! {

       let image = UIImage(data: i.img! as Data, scale: 1.0)

       self.quotesImgs.append(image!)
       print("is that really image? \(image)")
       print("app in for in sytax for coredata = \(self.quotesImgs)")



   }

   print("quotes \(self.quotes)")
   }
   ```

print is `result = [] / quotes Optional([])`

What am I missing??

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: @moonvader nope.. :( I used Realm